# How to extend or change the session timeout value i.e. session.maxAge in Play Framework (Java)

Tags: java, session-cookies, playback

I am new to Play Framework and working on session Management. My requirement is, I need to change the session TimeOut value to certain value when user is still using the application (webpage).

Condition:
If user has been logged in, and the timeout value it 30 minutes. User is working on the same application and the session should be expired after 30 minutes of interval time. As the session timeout is 30 minutes it is expiring and sending user to login page. I want a way to handle the session so that when the user is accessing the application and session is near to end. I want to change the value to double. So that user can use same session.

This is default value I have set

`###session timeout is 30 minutes (1800000 Milliseconds)
play.http.session.maxAge = 1800000`

I am using below way for checking session validation in Play Framework using Java. Please find the sample code.

```
public class SessionValidatorAction extends Action.Simple{ 

public CompletionStage<Result> call(Context ctx) 

    {

      ctx.session().get("user");

    }

}
```

#### Below are the link for the same session management in Play:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaActionsComposition#Action-composition

Note:
I did not find any methods in session obejct like we get in java(J2EE)
 Session.setMaxInactiveInterval(15*60); 
Please guide me.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Inherit the filter class and implement the apply method. So, if you call "withsession in "result:Result" as parameter of previous session, new session will be created. Of course, the expiration time will be extended again.

sorry I'm not good at English. I hope this helps.

here is my code by Scala

```
    @Singleton
    class SessionDelayFilter @Inject()(implicit override val mat: Materializer,
                                       exec: ExecutionContext) extends Filter {
      override def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])
                        (requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
        nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>
          result.withSession(result.session(requestHeader))
        }
      }
    }
```